# $.ajax load in UI dialog() append issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, jsonp

I'm loading data coming from ajax dataType:jsonp into a jquery UI dialog(). 
The data is displaying by appending the results to `<li>`

```
$.each(data.SearchResponse.Image.Results,
    function(i, item) {
        console.log(item.Thumbnail.Url);
        $("#Results").append("<li><img style='width:100px; height:75px;' src='" + item.Thumbnail.Url + "'/></li>");
    });
}
```

If i have 2 instances of the dialog() open, the first dialog is able to get and append the results where as the second dialog is getting , but not appending the results.

The second case is, If i only have one dialog open, then i'm able to see the results, but if i close it and open it again, results are no longer appended. I do see the results in console.log, but it's just not being appended, why is that.

What is causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have two divs both with id="Results"? try giving them separate names, or use class="Results" and change #Results to .Results? jQuery only lets you modify the first element if there are two with the same id.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I referenced class instead of id and that did it. i'm just wondering why it wasn't working with the one dialog case, where if i first open the dialog it works, but then if i close it  then open it, it no longer works. why is dialog counting ID as twice after close and open.